# Android WebView - code that can display and play a podcast can't play a YouTube video

Tags: android, android-webview

I have this code which works to display a WebView and use it:

```
WebView webview = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  //setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //setContentView(R.layout.podcasts);


  webview = new WebView(this);
  webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webview.setInitialScale(1);
  webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
     }
});




  //webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


  WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  //webSettings.getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture();
  webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
  webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
  webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
  webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
  webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

  setContentView(webview);
  webview.loadUrl("url_to_go_to");
```

But when I try to use this code to point to a YouTube channel, it just shows a blank screen.
Any idea why that would happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In order to get HTML5 videos to show up you need to enable the following things in the WebView:

```
WebView view;
... //initialize WebView
WebSettings webViewSettings = view.getSettings();
view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){}); //just added this
webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
webViewSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
```

You also need to put `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in your AndroidManifest. Otherwise, HTML5 stuff like YouTube videos won't work.

Comment: I am able to play the video and the audio plays, but the screen of the youtube is black. Have you ever had that happen?

Comment: I haven't seen that. What device and Android version are you testing on? Also, one more thing to fix in your code, put return false; instead of view.loadUrl(url);
         return true; in shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

Comment: Actually at the moment my biggest problem is that there is some redirect happening and if I don't comment this:      webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return false;
         }
     }); then the redirect prevents the YouTube channel page from loading.

Comment: Don't put loadUrl() inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading, it's likely what's causing the redirect. Just return false.

Comment: Just tried it without that line, and same thing. It just displays a gray screen and not going to the youtube channel page :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34241/discussion-between-genadinik-and-a-c-r-development)

Comment: @anthonycr you are a genie.
Genadinik you should set this answer as a correct answer!!!!!